# how to take the link with its variables from the page

Tags: php

how can i take the link of the page that i am on with its variables ?
example i have the page link is

```
 article.php?article_id=10&article_title=title&lang=ar
```

when i use the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] variable it takes only article.php

and im rewriting the url as well so it looks like this

```
  article/10/title/ar
```

what i want to do is just make a link that is to an English page so im trying to make it look like this

```
  article/10/title/en
```

how can i do that?

Comment: This depends entirely on what web server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will have all the parameters. You can also check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and that should contain the whole url, file and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data looks like its passed with a HTTP GET method, you can use this

```
$_GET["lang"];
```

This returns the value assigned to "lang"

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$params = $_GET;
$params['lang'] = 'en';

$link = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . implode('/', $params);
```